# In Azure DevOps, can you create a service connection for a container registry dynamically?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, containers

As part of my pipeline, I am creating a new Azure Registry Container and then building and pushing a container to it.

Normally to push to a registry I can just run this task.

```
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'todeleteaksdemoacr'
      repository: 'webappdocker'
      command: 'buildAndPush'
      Dockerfile: 'WebAppDocker/Dockerfile'
      tags: 'prod'
```

This only works if I have a Service Connection set up.

[image]

However, in my case, the registry container is being created in a previous step within my pipeline. So I don't have a service connection available for it.

When I run the pipeline, I'm getting the error "There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Job1: Step Docker input containerRegistry references service connection todeleteaksdemoacr which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

[image]

The service connection cannot be found obviously because the container registry doesn't exist. How can I get around this? Is there another way to push to the container registry?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this instead and it worked

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Login to ACR'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '<sub ID>'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az acr login --name ${{parameters.acr_name}}
        docker build -t <conatinername>:prod .
        docker push ${{parameters.acr_name}}.azurecr.io/<containername>:prod
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [Docker@1 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v1?view=azure-pipelines) to build and push the image like as below.

```yaml
steps:
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'Build image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(ArmConnection)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(AcrName)'
    command: 'build'
    dockerFile: path/to/Dockerfile
    imageName: '$(image_name):$(image_tag)'

- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'Push image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(ArmConnection)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(AcrName)'
    command: 'push'
    imageName: '$(image_name):$(image_tag)'
```

You can use the pipeline variables/parameters to dynamically specify the values for the following inputs:

- **`$(ArmConnection)`** can be either an ARM service connection or an Azure Subscription that contains the ACR.
- **`$(AcrName)`** is the name of the ACR.
- **`$(image_name)`** is the name of the Docker image will be built. It also is name of the Container repository.
- **`$(image_tag)`** is the tag of the image.

---

Comment: @Diskdrive, Is there any update from you? I'd like to know whether the method that using **`Docker@1`** task is also work fine for you.